# Individual plots into one figure using matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

The goal is to generate a single figure with multiple subplots. 
The following code generates 4 separate plots

**Sublists to plot: Can the same loop be used on both sets of data? x vs. y and b vs. p**
The difference between the two data sets is x vs. y will make 4 plots while b vs. p will make 2

```
x = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]

p = [[17, 16, 6, 15, 6, 7, 6, 7, 9, 11], [16, 13, 9, 11, 12, 13, 6, 12, 13, 7]]
b = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]

colours=['r','g','b','k']
```

**Loop that plots them**

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i],colours[i])
    plt.show()
```

Is it possible to create a function that loops through each created plot and adds it to one figure or a single pdf so that all 4 plots can be viewed at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem using `subplots`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
colours=['r','g','b','k']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
i = 0 # moving index to plot different sublists of data 
for r in axes:
    for c in r:
        c.plot(x[i], y[i], color=colours[i], label='Sublist %d'%(i+1))
        i += 1
        c.legend()

plt.show()
```

Alternative approach as suggested by @SpghttCd

```
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ax.plot(x[i], y[i], color=colours[i], label='Sublist %d'%(i+1))
    ax.legend()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Dataset 2** (as provided in the comments below:

```
x = [[17, 16, 6, 15, 6], [7, 6, 7, 9, 11], [16, 13, 9, 11, 12], [13, 6, 12, 13, 7]] 
y = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

**Output (Dataset 2)**

[image]

Comment: Note that for better comparability there are these very convenient kwargs of subplot: sharex and sharey. Set to True, all subplots have the according axis equally scaled with the other subplots. Set to 'col' or 'row' these properties can even be limited to column- or row-wise.

Comment: You could do this in a single loop by iterating over axes.flatten(). I.e. for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):...

Comment: @SpghttCd: Thanks for the comment. You are right, One can do that. It's a matter of personal taste I guess. I personally use the above method because it gives me an idea of how the plots are splitted in rows as I often work with large number of subplots.

Comment: I added your suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Agreed of course, matter of taste and context. Sometimes still having access to both index dimensions may be necessary. Here with the index i, the use of enumerate makes sense imo. Thanks for adding!

Comment: Das stimmt! :) :)

Comment: This works until I try to use the for loop in a different set of data then I see the error:  ` for r in axes:
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable`

Comment: Can you share the other data on which you are trying to use it

Comment: p = [[17, 16, 6, 15, 6], [7, 6, 7, 9, 11], [16, 13, 9, 11, 12], [13, 6, 12, 13, 7]]
b = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]

Comment: It works fine for me for your new data set as well. See my edited answer for your new dataset

Comment: Ahhh ok here is were I'm having trouble: I want to be able to use this loop on lists of different sizes. when p and b are not the same list size as x and y, I get an index out of range error. for example if p = [[17, 16, 6, 15, 6, 7, 6, 7, 9, 11], [16, 13, 9, 11, 12, 13, 6, 12, 13, 7]] and
b = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]

Comment: What do you want to plot? B versus p OR x versus y? Please be elaborative to save time in multiple comments. If possible edit your question with a simple input of what all p, b, x,y you want to plot Otherwise making multiple edits to the answer without knowing what You want is just not worth it